# Term_evals when finding hyper parameters for XGBoost with #mlr3

Tags: mlr3

I'm new to gradient boosting (XGBoost). I've read the manual for mlr3, and if I understand it right, I want to first tune my hyper parameters. I'm unsure for this how to set term_evals? In the tutorial, it uses a very small number and says for real applications a higher number is needed. how do I know whether the number I've picked is high enough?

Many thanks

I ran instance=tune(...) with different numbers of term_evals. Of course, it takes longer with more. I inspected instance$result (instance=tune(...)), but from this I have no idea how to know whether term_evals was large enough or not.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing the right budget for tuning is a difficult practical challenge. You can find out more in section "6.5 When to Terminate HPO" in our [hyperparameter optimization paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.05847). You could use a time limit instead of the number of evaluation. You set a time limit that is feasible for you e.g. one day if you run it on your local machine. Usually it is better to evaluate more configurations.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! Just to check, I've set my term_time now to 30min. So that's how long it takes, but when I then want to use the optimised parameters of this to train my model, it takes <1 min. Is that right?
I use :
`tuned.paras = instance$result_learner_param_vals
my.learner$param_set$values = tuned.paras
my.learner$train(my.task)
`

Comment: The code is correct and yes tuning takes longer than fitting a single model because tuning requires fitting a lot of models.